# mysql: Joining two select statements?

Tags: mysql, select

I need these to work together to create a table. Ive tried Union and Union All but unfortunately it just adds all the data into the first column (which is country).

```
Create table Final as
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(location,',',-1) AS Country
    FROM raw_data##Getting just
```

the country code from each specific field

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(book_rating,'null',1) AS Ratings
FROM raw_data
```

Also is there a better way to add the column book_ratings? there is nothing special special about it. i only need the whole thing and not truncated values.

I just thought it might work this way somehow..

Comment: do they have a common column on which you can join them?

Comment: I don't want to join them TOGEHER. I'd jst like to put them both columns iin the same table but it seems i cannot since MySQL only reads the first select statement and spits out the second in console.

Comment: yup, if you want that you'd have to do it in php or some other language, but that's not what mysql is build for. you could do a join and then group by, it would work. it would be slower though

Comment: I think i have a solution, let me check first

Comment: are you selecting 2 things from the same table? maybe i've misread and made it a whole lot harder then it is. what are the 2 tables you want something from? you select multiple columns in one query i'm sure you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you wanted?

```
Create table Final as
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(location,',',-1) AS Country,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(book_rating,'null',1) AS Ratings
FROM raw_data
```

That seems too easy a thing to ask, but after rereading the question that seems what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes that was it. All i had to do was not repeat a second 'SELECT'. Thanks Jester!!

Comment: @b0uncyfr0 no problem, good luck with the rest of your project!